# prerequesties software with condition is possible?

Tags: wpf, installation, prerequisites

I have created wpf window application setup with prerequisites software adobe reader 11.0 and flash 14.0 and K-Lite Codec Pack and WMP(Windows Media Player) 11.0 using bootsrapper.Its working fine when i install my wpf setup.

But my question is, K-Lite Codec Pack and WMP 11.0 only install, if client system is XP else install only adobe reader 10.0 and flash 14.0.

Is this Possible???

if yes, how???

Answer (score 2):

You should easily build a setup package with prerequisites using an installer application. I use for several years [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/) which personally I think is a really easy to use app. For example, using Advanced Installer you can easy configure the target OSs for a preq within their [Prerequisites](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-professional.html#prerequisites) page. Hope this is useful.